# Owners of Epic Games forum

Tags: unreal-tournament-3

I'm trying to register over at the [Epic Games forums](http://forums.epicgames.com/), but cannot. They require you to enter the first name of the owner of the forum.

I've googled and binged the hell out of this, the info cannot be found anywhere. Can someone please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[As the Wikipedia article mentions right at the start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_games), the answer is "Epic MegaGames"

Answer (score 3):

You should re-read the challenge question on their registration form. It does not ask for "owner" names, but the **name of the company**:

> Enter the first name of the company that runs these forums. - [Epic Games forum](http://forums.epicgames.com/register.php?do=register)

Answer (score -2):

Would it not be Epic as in epic games.